# Mocking HTTPS request using mountebank

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, mountebank

Hi I have created one HTTPS service using mountebank tool - however I am getting "Socket Hang Up " error during impostor creation. Below are the steps followed

1. Added the CA authorized certificate in postman tool under 'Settings under that Certificates tab'.
2. Impostor creation

Impostor config:

```
{
  "port": 4549,
  "protocol": "https",
  "mutualAuth": true,
  "key": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nKLBP7HSOBEeH1oKdp5tCIa8=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "cert": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nRKBzyPQF3Ts=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
  "stubs": [
    {
      "responses": [
        {
          "is": {
            "body": {
              "accountNum": "123456789",
              "statusCode": 200
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "predicates": [
        {
          "equals": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/test",
            "headers": {
              "Accept": "text/plain",
              "Name": "abc"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're cool posting your private key to the interweb?